# Creating a dynamic 2D matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, 2d

I want a dynamic matrix, number rows and columns unkonw, filling it by clicking on a button. Bu there is more: I don't want to add entire rows, but just one cell at the time, one click = one cell added. Of course not randomly : 1st cell of 1st row, 2nd cell of 1st row... and then the same of the 2nd row and so one...

I know about UJMP, ArrayList, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. Please be accurate on your answer, thank you in advance.

Comment: "Please be accurate"?  You haven't given enough information to give an accurate answer.

Comment: I meant answer with example if posible, but I cannot give more information because that's exactly my problem.

Comment: @guts: My point was that your question is not at all clear.  What *precisely* do you want to be able to do?  What is wrong with a standard Java (multi-dimensional) array, or a storage class like ArrayList?

Comment: The problem is you can only add entire rows/columns, I want to add just one cell at the time. For example  : 1st button click = adding M[1][1] (at this time, this is all what my matrix contains). 2nd button click = M[1][2]...and so one.

Comment: Anyone ? I really need help here :(

Comment: Do you want a _sparse_ matrix?

Comment: Why not just use a `List<List<?>>`? Also, if don't know (or can't derive) the number of columns, how do you know when to add a new row?

Comment: If you don't know the number of columns, then how many cells do you fill before moving to the next row? Without further clarification, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Using Joel suggestion you can even create your own collections to emulate a dynamic matrix like ArrayList does for lower level arrays ([]).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
List<List<Integer>> dynamicMatrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

dynamicMatrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
dynamicMatrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
dynamicMatrix.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

dynamicMatrix.get(0).add(6);
dynamicMatrix.get(0).add(7);
dynamicMatrix.get(0).add(8);

System.out.println(dynamicMatrix.get(0).get(0)); // 6
System.out.println(dynamicMatrix.get(0).get(1)); // 7
System.out.println(dynamicMatrix.get(0).get(2)); // 8
```