# How to create 3 dimentional dynamic array?

Tags: java

I want to create 3d dynamic array. How should I create this?

I am collecting data form database and I am trying to store this data in array and I don't know how much data c

Answer (score 3):

An array is, once created, not resizable. So you either have to create new arrays over and over and copy the values of you use an arraylist:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> matrix3d = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();
```

And to use it:

```
// create a matrix 2x3x4 matrix (a_111 ... a_234)

// the matrix first
List<List<List<Integer>>> matrix3d = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();

// add two 2d matrices
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   subMatrix2d = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   matrix3d.add(subMatrix2d);

   // add three 1d matrices
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       subMatrix1d = new ArrayList<Integer>(4); // initial value to clarify only!
       subMatrix2d.add(subMatrix1d);
   }
}


// set a_223 to value 4
matrix3d.get(1).get(1).set(2, 4);  // matrix/list indices are zero based
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533484/java-dynamic-2d-matrix/5533915#5533915) for a simple dynamic 2D array with primitives. You could improve it for 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not implement a Coodinate class:

```
public  class Coordinate<T> {
    final double x;
    final double y;
    final double z;
    T data;


    public Coordinate(double x, double y, double z, T data) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

After,
 List positions = new ArrayList();

And therefor, insert the positions:

positions.add(new Coodinate(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) ;

May be, for what you want to do, could be faster and easier to develop and test.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObjectType>>> myThreeDimensionalVector = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObjectType>>>();`

More seriously, it's a pita.  Can you describe why you're trying to do this so that maybe we can suggest better ways to do it?

Comment: refer to it be interface - i.e. `List`

Comment: I am collecting 2 values form database material group, problem description and I am going to read 1st value put in array & make counter value as 1 now read next value compare it with previous array value if it matches both material group and problem increase counter else store it in array...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're better off creating an Object to hold your data (1 instance per row) and add each instance to a List (~ 1-dim array).

Answer (score 0):

that array looks strange to me,
if i may suggest my  solution:
first define a class with two variables, call that class AClass, then use a hashmap(if insert order is not important) to save your counter as index and the instance of AClass as the value.
something like this :`HashMap<Integer,AClass>` .
and if insert order is important to you , use linkedHashmap